# HTML textbox presentation for large strings

Tags: html

I am working with an HTML input element that is about 10 to 12 characters in size.  A user is free to enter any length of string into this field.  However, when the user is finished and leaves focus of the textbox, the field shows the latest portion of the string.  I want it to show the initial part of the string.

Is this possible?

[image: Sample]

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle of your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: that's not the default behavior of input text. Please share your markup

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: I've created a basic fiddle and it seems (in chrome anyway) that this occurs: http://jsfiddle.net/9zswjtqe/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, None of that deals with what I am trying to do.

Comment: @1l13v I know it's not the default behavior of input text.  That is why I am trying to work out how it can be done.  My markup is nothing unique. It's a a table where a single column of cells is just input.

Comment: @AlvinPascoe Thanks for trying.  The page is going to be loaded through C# WebView class.  So it is most likely going to use IE rather than Chrome.  And IE doesn't automatically do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample HTML:

```
<label><input type="text" name="input" id="text_field" /></label>
```

One jQuery, dirty&hack-ish, but working solution (not sure about CSS or other possibilities):

```
$('body').on('blur','#text_field', function() {
    new_field = $(this).clone();

    $(this).remove();
    $('label').append(new_field);
});
```

**DEMO>** http://jsfiddle.net/9zswjtqe/4/

Idea is - clone (deep) element on blur, remove it, and attach new element/clone (with desired text position this time). Tested in Firefox, IE, Chrome. Works fine.

Comment: That seems a touch excessive to wipe out and replace an entire field.  And it appears to remove any direct event listeners on the element when the page is loaded. But I will keep this in mind.

Comment: While waiting for better solution - http://jsfiddle.net/9zswjtqe/9/ event handlers are working, with clone() parameters set to true: https://api.jquery.com/clone/  clone(true,true)